# symfony2 : I want to set two column in a row in doctrine in a query

Tags: symfony

I want to update a two columns in a row..Please help...

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('b')
                   ->update()
                   ->set('b.user1', $user,'b.tempid', $user1)
                   ->where('b.id ='.$id );
```

this give me the query

```
UPDATE Shopper\ShopBundle\Entity\Items b SET b.user1 = 1 WHERE b.id =213
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this
separate the one statement of set in  to two

```
->set('b.user1', $user)
->set('b.tempid', $user1)
```